# Drupal : Notification of modification to translator of a content

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-modules

In Drupal, i want to know how to notify translator that the content they translated, was modified.

What is the easiest way to do it? Is there a module for that?  Maybe workflow can help but i think this needs too much adminsitration

Bonus Question : Do you already work with the same language in several countries? Exemple : English US, Englis UK, English CA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)** is an excellent module for setting up notifications and other Trigger -> Action relationships. I don't know if it works with translations out-of-the-box, but you may be able to find an applicable extension or write a custom module to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

In fact i found this page and i think this module can help me : http://drupal.org/project/translation_management

Too bad for me, i need it now.

So i'll try this module : http://drupal.org/project/icanlocalize